# Async post model and load response with MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I have 2 partial views, each with their own distinct model, on a single page. I want to asynchronously post the data from one partial view (it's a form) then take the response from the controller and load it into the second partial view.

Basically my page would be structured as follows.

Parent view:

```
<div id="viewA">
    @Html.Partial("_viewA, Model.viewA)
</div>
<div id="viewB">
    <p>Loading...</p>
</div>
```

_viewA:

```
@model ModelA

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Thing)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Thing)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
}
```

_viewB:

```
@model ModelB

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Column 1
        </th>
        <th>
            Column 2
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Col1)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Col2)
        </td>
    }
</table>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Something([Bind(Include="Thing")] ModelA modela)
{
    //do stuff
    ModelB modelb = new ModelB();
    return PartialView("_viewB", modelb);
}
```

Javascript:

```
//I'm not sure...
//Probably some AJAX call
//Then we stick the response into div#viewB
```

The key is that I need this all to happen asynchronously. User fills out the form clicks a button, data is sent to the server, response is returned, part of the page updates, all without a post back.

What Javascript (and other changes) do I need to get this all working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ajax to submit your form and when the ajax call's response callback, update the DOM as needed.

So let's add an `Id` to the form element, which we can use for wiring up the ajax behavior

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Something","Student",FormMethod.Post,new { id="studForm"}))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Thing)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Thing)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
}
```

Now Use this javascript to listen to the submit event, prevent the default form submit(as we are going to do an ajax post), serialize the form and send via `$.post` method. You can use the jQuery `serialize` method to get the serialized version of the form.

```
$(function(){

   $("#studForm").submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();  //prevent normal form submission

       var actionUrl = $(this).attr("action");  // get the form action value
       $.post(actionUrl ,$(this).serialize(),function(res){
          //res is the response coming from our ajax call. Use this to update DOM
          $("#viewB").html(res);
       });
   });

});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!